# Position LinearLayout below Toolbar

Tags: android

i have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="imagelimit"
        type="int" />

</data>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordlt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/incltoolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/baseLlt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="155dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/no_pet_images_yet"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/pet_images_limit"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/imageGrdv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addImageFlbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

i would like to show LinearLayout (@+id/baseLlt) below toolbar wihout adding margin top attribute to it(toolbar height is not the same for all kind of devices). Is there a proper solution to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please post "layout/toolbar" and your activity code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply wrap your `Toolbar` and `LinearLayout` in a vertical `LinearLayout`, something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordlt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/incltoolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/baseLlt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="155dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_pet_images_yet"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/pet_images_limit"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/imageGrdv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addImageFlbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this code

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordlt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/incltoolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/baseLlt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="155dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_pet_images_yet"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/pet_images_limit"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/imageGrdv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addImageFlbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add xml property to your CoordinatorLayout and toolbar

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

also add xml property to your linearlayout

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**xml**

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordlt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/incltoolbar"

            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/baseLlt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="155dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/no_pet_images_yet"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/pet_images_limit"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/imageGrdv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addImageFlbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="@{imagelimit != 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

hope it helps !!!!